# Does Spring Data Solr work with zookeeper host?

Tags: spring, solr, apache-zookeeper, spring-data-solr

I have a spring boot application and in my properties file I have:

```
spring.data.solr.host=http://{SOLR.HOST}/solr
```

This works fine but if I replaced the `SOLR.HOST` with `ZOOKEEPER.HOST`, it throws an I/O exception while talking to the server. It seems to me that spring data is trying to hit the zookeeper endpoint directly through http request, and zookeeper doesn't handle http requests? If so what can I do to allow spring data to work with zookeeper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to use the CloudSolrClient to instantiate the SolrClient bean 
https://dzone.com/articles/spring-data-solr-cloud-zookeeper-mongodb-ubuntu-in

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages = { "ca.knc.restaurant.repository.solr" }, multicoreSupport = true)
public class SpringSolrConfig {
    @Value("${spring.data.solr.zk-host}")
    private String zkHost;
    @Bean
    public SolrClient solrClient() {
        return new CloudSolrClient(zkHost);
    }
    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(SolrClient solrClient) throws Exception {
        return new SolrTemplate(solrClient);
    }
}
```

You can also set it through the application.properties and let Spring Boot autoconfigure it :

> spring.data.solr.zk-host= # ZooKeeper host address in the form
>   HOST:PORT.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/solr/SolrAutoConfiguration.java

---

Otherwise, you can use a LoadBalancer to serve your Solr Instances and use a regular Solr Host configuration

For example, I have the following configuration (yml config) :

```
spring.data.solr.host: https://foo.bar.com/solr
```

Where foo.bar.com serves one of my Solr instance with Apache as a standard Load Balancer.

Comment: I wasn't awared of `spring.data.solr.zk-host`. Thanks, +1